# FileSystemWatcher locks file, how to release it?

Tags: wpf, filesystemwatcher

I am using a FileSystemWatcher to raise the event when an image file is edited on Paint and update the preview image control using it. But setting the file as a source second time, it throws an error because the file is still in use by another process. So I discovered this is because of FileSystemWatcher.

**I have this code:**

```
    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(lastImage)) return;
        FileSystemWatcher izleyici = new FileSystemWatcher(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( lastImage),
            System.IO.Path.GetFileName(lastImage));
        izleyici.Changed += izleyici_Changed;
        izleyici.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        izleyici.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = lastImage;
        info.Verb = "edit";
        Process.Start(info);
    }

    void izleyici_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
       //I want to add code here to release the file. Dispose() not worked for me

       setImageSource(lastImage);
    }

    void setImageSource(string file)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.EndInit();
        }

        ssPreview.Source = bitmap;
    }
```

In this code I want to release the file before updating the `Image` control. I tried `Dispose` but it was not worked. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is neither locked by the FileSystemWatcher, nor by MS Paint. What actually happens is that you get an `InvalidOperationException`, because the FileSystemWatcher's `Changed` event is not fired in the UI thread, and hence the handler method can't set the Image control's `Source` property.

Invoking the image loading code in a Dispatcher action solves the issue:

```
void setImageSource(string file)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(
                                file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            ssPreview.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(
                stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But what do you mean `not fired in the UI Thread`? Would you give me a more detailed explanation to get the logic. It is important for me. Thanks again.

Comment: You may read the online documentation of the [Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class.